# Ignoring [Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I've setup my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` properly but I keep getting requests from all types of sites that cause this '[Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error' to be sent out.

How can I ignore this particular error?

Comment: What version of Django you're running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `SuspiciousOperation` exception is raised in Django's `CommonMiddleware` when the `Host:` http header doesn't match the required `ALLOWED_HOSTS` settings.  This exception is not treated specially, so errors are propagated through the logging system.

You can use the answer by lborgav to divert all error messages differently, but if you just want to just catch this one error you can design a custom middleware.

The following snippet is a [Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) class which you can add to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py` to squash just this error.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'myapp.middleware.SquashInvalidHostMiddleware',
    ....
]
```

This **must** occur before `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware`, since you want to detect the presence of the error condition and return a response immediately before progressing to the `CommonMiddleware` which would generate an exception.

```
# myapp/middleware/__init__.py

from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation
from django.views.defaults import server_error


class SquashInvalidHostMiddleware(object):
    """
    Middleware class to squash errors due to suspicious Host: headers.
    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        """
        Check for denied Hosts.
        """

        try:
            # Attempt to obtain Host: from http header.  This may elicit a
            # SuspiciousOperation if Host: doesn't match ALLOWED_HOSTS.
            # Unceremoniously squash these errors to prevent log emails,
            # diverting straight to 500 page.

            request.get_host()
        except SuspiciousOperation:
            return server_error(request)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your LOGGING configuration you can override handler class

```
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'class': 'django.utils.log.MyAdminEmailHandler',
    'include_html': True,
    }
},
```

Now you can write your class MyAdminEmailHandler. Check its code in [AdminEmailHandler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/log.py#L65)

In emit function, just get rid of report if (request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') not in settings.INTERNAL_IPS)